# I accidentally delete UEFI partition and now I can't boot Linux Mint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, linux-mint

I wanted to add more space for my disk partition, however, I didn't read carefully, and I accidentally deleted the UEFI partition. I still didn't notice how seriously it cause and after I rebooted, the GNU disappeared and replaced by the Grub Shell.

I already read some docs on Google how to boot using Grub Shell but it seemed some directories were missing in my computer ig. Now, I don't know how to fix it or just boot it? I just want I can boot the Linux Mint (ubuntu), and restore GNU is better.

My computer is running dual boot with Linux Mint and Windows.

Comment: You can try to restore the partition with TestDisk. Live environments like 
Hiren's BootCD should have it

Comment: If you can't recover the partition with `testdisk`, recreating the EFI partition and boot hierarchy is simple and the steps for Linux Mint should be on the developer's site, else a search engine should return how to do so

Comment: Just restore the full disk image you made before adjusting partitions. A full image restores *all* partitions.

Comment: I restored with TestDisk but it still show the Grub Shell instead of GNU. Now I want to recreate it, it is possible now? I searched but there are ways to do with Linux but I can't boot it currently :(

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to make a Linux Mint USB disk and boot from that. It will allow you to install to the hard drive.